# SAPUI5 change text dynamically based on context/route matched

Tags: xml, dynamic, view, localization, sapui5

I am currently working on one XML view which is used for the user creation and user editing process.

Is there an elegant way for example to change the title of the view depending on the mode (create user / edit user) i am using? Preferable a way without hiding DOM elements.

Comment: check the developer guide on [localization](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f217c46f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html), it has a lot of info.

Comment: he is not talking about localization, he is talking about the dynamic text to be set based on context

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: In your controller say **S1.controller.js** , if you are already defining headerFooter using `getHeaderFooterOptions` well and good. Else define it

```
    getHeaderFooterOption:function(){
    var that = this;
    var objHeaderFooterOptions = {
        sI18NFullscreenTitle: "CREATE_TITLE",//you need to define the value in i18n files
        //
        /*oEditBtn: {
            sId: "BTN_SEND",
            sI18nBtnTxt: "USER_CREATE",
            onBtnPressed: function(evt) {
                that.handleCreate(evt);
            }
        },*/
        buttonList: [
                 //your footer buttons go here
                  ]
    };
    return objHeaderFooterOptions;
    }
```

Now, in onInit() of controller:

```
onInit: function () {
    var that = this;
    this.oRouter.attachRouteMatched(function (oEvent) {

        if (oEvent.getParameter("name") === "create") { //the name you have given for the view in **Component.js**
            //your initial create login
        }
      //this will be executed whent you come as update context
        if (oEvent.getParameter("name") === "update") { //the name you have given for the view in Component.js
            var editContextHeaderFooter = that.getHeaderFooterOptions();
            editContextHeaderFooter.sI18NFullscreenTitle = "UPDATE_TITLE" //define the value in i18n file
                //you can edit other values also, example you want a different button in the footer.
            that.setHeaderFooterOptions(editContextHeaderFooter);

        }
    });
}
```

in metadata of **Component.js**

```
fullScreenPageRoutes : {
            // fill the routes to your full screen pages in here.
                "create" : {
                    "pattern" : "",
                    "view" : "S1"
                },
                "update" : {
                    "pattern" : "update/{context}",
                    "view" : "S1"
                }
            }
```

in **i18n.properties** file

```
#XTIT: Create Screen Title
CREATE_TITLE: Create New User

#XTIT: Update Screen Title
UPDATE_TITLE: Update User
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! Where did the "setHeaderFooterOptions" come from? If i try to call it, it says that this is not a function.

Comment: are you using scaffloding controller? if not, please put your controller code and xml view

Comment: Thats my code (i cut things out and renamed, so dont be confused) https://gist.github.com/anonymous/57281d751617c0ed7a96

Comment: delete whateve I have told!! :)
this is very easy.. give Id to your page. then set using this.byId("pageId").setTitle("your text");

Answer (score 0):

in case you are using plain UI5 application:

```
 onRouteMatched : function(oEvent) {
    var that = this;
    if (oEvent.getParameter("name") === "user") { //the name you have given for the view in **Component.js**
        //your initial create login
    that.byId("myPage").setTitle("Create New user");
   that.byId("objHeader").setTitle("Update user");
    }
  //this will be executed when you come as update context
    if (oEvent.getParameter("name") === "edituser") {

        that.byId("myPage").setTitle("Update user");
        that.byId("objHeader").setTitle("Update user");
    }
  }
```

similary in **XML** add IDs:

```
<Page id="myPage" class="sapUiFioriObjectPage" title="{i18n>createNewUserHdrTitle}"
        showNavButton="true" navButtonTap="onNavBack">
        <ObjectHeader id="objHeader" title="{i18n>createNewUserHdrTitle}">
        </ObjectHeader>
    </Page>
```

if you are using i18n texts make sure you bind the translation resources to your view.

Comment: Basically this is the way i did not want to go, because this is too much UI logic in the controller file. Is there a way to use prefixes? For example `{i18n>{new_}title}` and `{i18n>{edit_}title}`?

Comment: There is no other solution which I know of!